# Firebase error on .getReference

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suddenly we are getting below error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
       at blq.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11518446:56)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Everything was working fine in the current version as well as other app versions, but this issue is coming now for all app versions.

We are using 25.3.1 support lib version and 11.0.2 play services version.

Strange Fact:

Working absolutely as expected if use new/sandbox firebase database.

More logs
11-04 17:37:35.560 15770-15784/com.nobroker.app D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( ff8081814c58efc3014c6a0a558f32ff ).
11-04 17:37:35.560 15770-15770/com.nobroker.app D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
11-04 17:37:35.560 15770-15770/com.nobroker.app D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
11-04 17:37:35.561 15770-15876/com.nobroker.app D/RepoOperation: Auth token changed, triggering auth token refresh
11-04 17:37:35.561 15770-15770/com.nobroker.app D/AppController: signInWithCustomToken:onComplete:true
11-04 17:37:35.561 15770-15876/com.nobroker.app D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Auth token refreshed.
11-04 17:37:35.561 15770-15770/com.nobroker.app I/deekshant: recording event. Category: CUSTOM_EVENTS Event:FAILED_FIREBASE_AUTH Extras: {src=AFTER_PUBLIC_LOGIN}
11-04 17:37:35.567 15770-15847/com.nobroker.app D/FA: Logging event (FE): select_content, Bundle[{item_name=FAILED_FIREBASE_AUTH, firebase_event_origin(_o)=app, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=NBLauncherActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3142508212762295688, item_category=CUSTOM_EVENTS, content_type=CUSTOM_EVENTS, item_id=FAILED_FIREBASE_AUTH}]
11-04 17:37:35.596 15770-15847/com.nobroker.app D/FA: Logging event (FE): CUSTOM_EVENTS, Bundle[{item_name=FAILED_FIREBASE_AUTH, firebase_event_origin(_o)=app, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=NBLauncherActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3142508212762295688, item_category=CUSTOM_EVENTS, content_type=CUSTOM_EVENTS, item_id=FAILED_FIREBASE_AUTH}]
11-04 17:37:35.707 15770-15770/com.nobroker.app V/deekshant: onActivityStopped count 2
11-04 17:37:35.707 15770-15770/com.nobroker.app V/deekhshant: onActivityDestroyed count 1
11-04 17:37:35.717 15770-15876/com.nobroker.app D/WebSocket: ws_1 - closed
11-04 17:37:35.717 15770-15876/com.nobroker.app D/WebSocket: ws_1 - closing itself
11-04 17:37:35.717 15770-15876/com.nobroker.app D/Connection: conn_1 - Realtime connection failed
11-04 17:37:35.717 15770-15876/com.nobroker.app D/Connection: conn_1 - closing realtime connection
11-04 17:37:35.717 15770-15876/com.nobroker.app D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Got on disconnect due to OTHER
11-04 17:37:35.717 15770-15876/com.nobroker.app D/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Scheduling connection attempt
11-04 17:37:35.717 15770-15876/com.nobroker.app D/ConnectionRetryHelper: Scheduling retry in 892ms
11-04 17:37:35.899 15770-15919/com.nobroker.app E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
                                                                         at blq.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC@11518438:56)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
11-04 17:37:35.902 15770-15847/com.nobroker.app D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=NBLauncherActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-3142508212762295688, timestamp=1509797255900, fatal=1}]

Answer (score 0):

Finally, We resolved the issue. It was because of the change in response-header which was coming from firebase server. 
Google patched few firebase server on which our instance was running.
And response header which was expected to be name: "Upgrade" value: "websocket" changed to "upgrade".

Reply from Google:

"I'm really sorry for breaking your app. Indeed our latest version changed the response header from "Upgrade: websocket" to "upgrade: websocket". Even though headers are case insensitive, our very own SDK code is not spec compliant."

Once google fixed the header issue, It was resolved.